# Is it possible to replace the (Fat) PS3's optical drive with a PC Optical Drive?

Tags: pc, ps3

If the optical drive for a fat Ps3 is failing, would be able to open it and in it's place install either a standard internal PC optical drive or an external optical drive. I don't want it to look pretty, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

No, the drive has a special ribbon connector and is also slanted as seen in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UB7nsTSCD4) video. You can order one online however.